# How to to split an element to make a rotation point to animate a follow path

Tags: animation, modifiers, constraints

I am trying to animate a double bus, like this one:

[image]

Do I need to split the bus in the middle so that both bus parts can rotate individually over a path using the *Follow Path* constraint? I don't have enough experience in animating to know how to achieve this. Any suggestions? This is my bus so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two:

[image]

I looked into the *Follow Path* constraint a bit more, but could not come up with anything. I instead decided to rig the bus. Basically, I added a base bone with a *Follow Path* constraint and two bones on either end with *Follow Path* constraints and an *Offset:* value to make sure they stayed at the front and rear of the bus. I then added two bones for the two halves of the bus. They are following the base bone's movements (parented) and have a *Track To* constraint so they point towards the two end bones. I did all the weight painting myself, so it would take forever to write a lengthy tutorial. Instead, I explained what I did, and am including a second .blend file. **Note that you may want to adjust the start and end values in the .blend file.**

[image]

Comment: Well, I have to admid that this is working quite well, not perfect but if I spend more time on it, it should work. I always avoid working with bones because I don't understand one single thing of them so here a few questions. 1)You said you added 2 bones for the bus halves but I count 5? 2)I can't find the follow path contraint you added

Comment: 1) Two bones actually move the bus. The other 3 simply provide targets that keep the original 2 moving and pointing in the right direction. 2) Ctrl + Tab into pose mode with the bones selected and go to the newly appearing _Bone Constraints_ tab in the _Properties panel_. 3) If my answer helped, please consider accepting it. 4) If you fool with the weight painting on the bus object, you could very well eventually get a smoother movement.

Comment: You're very welcome. Always glad to help.

Comment: Hey, I have a new questions: http://puu.sh/p3tW7/9fa24a0ddc.png .1) Did you create bones in edit mode from the horizontal bone? 2) If I select all bones and the mesh, what parent option do I need to select?

Comment: 1) ya 2) I am not sure @Vinc199789

Comment: And did you add the Track_front and Track_back bones in edit mode or are these lose bones parented?

Comment: They are not parented.

Comment: Is it possible that you can make a small video of how you rig + adding the contraints?? I keep failing getting the bones correct.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will do much better using a *Curve* object modifier than a *Follow Path* constraint.

To utilize this, first delete the constraint. Next, align the center point of your mesh with that of the curve (make the locations the same). Then, go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*. After that, add a *Curve* modifier. Select the curve in the dropdown menu that you want your mesh to follow. Play with the *Deformation Axis:* until your mesh is aligned along the curve the way you want. Your modifier should now look something like this:

[image]

To move your mesh along the curve, move the arrow that corresponds to the *Deformation Axis:* you selected.

[image]

Here is a .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. I also experimented with this but the problem is that at the mesh also deforms at the outside. I thought maybe could the follow path contraint solve this issue